# SpringBoot: Failed to Start : Field <field Name >in RestController required a bean of type

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am getting issue while startig up my Spring-boot project.

**Interface:**

```
import com.sample.rest.entity.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

}
```

**Rest Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customers")
public class CustomerRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepositoryInterface custRepo;

   
    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Customer> getAllCustomers(){
      return custRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Application class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.sample.rest")
public class SpringbootRestApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootRestApiApplication.class, args);
    }    
    
}
```

Build is happening fine, but while running the spring-boot application, I am getting the following error.

**Console:**

> *Task :bootRun
> [2020-07-19T19:46:13.013Z] [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext] [restartedMain] [559] [WARN ] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'custRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.rest.utility.CustomerRepositoryInterface' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> Exception in thread "task-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getProperties(SessionFactoryImpl.java:503)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.findDataSource(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:105)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:97)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> [2020-07-19T19:46:13.013Z] [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] [restartedMain] [40] [ERROR]
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> *************************** Description: Field custRepo in com.sample.rest.controller.CustomerRestController required a bean of
> type 'com.sample.rest.utility.CustomerRepositoryInterface' that could
> not be found. The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>   Action: Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.sample.rest.utility.CustomerRepositoryInterface' in your
>   configuration.*

Any idea/solution from anyone will be helpful.

Comment: what is say hello is doing inside main class

Comment: @silentsudo Its just a comment.... you can ignore that please. It was initially i added to check the structure working or not. But when I added the Interface and auto wired it, it started giving the  issue I mentioned and failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**
Found the issue, it was with project structure.

Previously my "SpringbootRestApiApplication.java" file was under "src/main/java/com/simple/rest/api" pkg.

I just put it under "src/main/java/com/simple/rest", because my other java files are under "src/main/java/com/simple/rest/*"

So I put the file under parent pkg. It got resolved.
Also now I do not need to specify the "scanBasePackages" any more.